# Sum of first and last digit of a number

Tags: c++

The problem is to find sum of first and second digit of a number.
If number is smaller than 10 then print number itself.
I wrote this code but i don't know why output is wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
 using namespace std; 
int main()
{
    int t,a,n,l;
     cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        cin>>n;
        if(n<10)
        {
           cout<<n;
        }
        else
        {
         a=n%10;
         l=n/10;
        cout<<a+l<<endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: " if number is greater than 10 then print number itself", really? If this is the correct description then you never have to extract digits from any number (because numbers <10 have only a single digit)

Comment: Not sure if that's the case, but seems like you've forgotten to add endl if n<10. So instead of this: cout<<n try this: "cout<<n<<endl"

Comment: what iss sample arguments and output that you said it is wrong?

Comment: Your problem description not logical please try to explain more clearly.

Comment: Problem heading says, First and last digit of a number but problem explanation says first and second digit.. please correct one of them.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your solution is wrong because `n/10` won't give you the first digit :)

If this is for a question for competitive programming(since you're taking in `t` test cases), I'll suggest taking input as a string assuming that input is always a valid int.

```
std::string s;
cin >> s;
if (s.size() == 1) std::cout << s << std::endl;
else std::cout << int(s.front() - '0') + int(s.back()-'0') << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

extracting of required digits is wrong in your solution. 
Please find solution for adding first and last digit of a number at
https://onlinegdb.com/Byro9hCMI or below:

its small and hence pasting it here as well:

```
#include <iostream>
 using namespace std; 
int main()
{
    int first, last, number;
    cin>>number;
    first = number % 10;

    while((number = number/10)>0)
    {
        last = number;
    }
    cout << endl << first+last << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Two Add first two digit (unit and tens)at https://onlinegdb.com/SJXNThAzI or below:

```
#include <iostream>
 using namespace std; 
int main()
{
    int first, second, number;
    cin>>number;
    first = number % 10;
    number = number/10;
    second = number %10;
    cout << endl << first+second << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's no need to flush output - use ordinary `'\n'` rather than `std::endl`.

Comment: @toby speight: thnaks for pointing it out, noted.